# SnowSQL (Snowflake) query result with newline

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've got the results of a Snowflake query which produces a newline '\r\n' (Char(10),Char(13)).
When this runs in the web GUI the results look like a Yaml file. (With newlines).
When run in the SnowSQL CLI and output to a file "test.yml" it returns all lines in 1 with the '\r\n' instead of a newline.
Has anyone encountered similar?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Can you share the actual output seen in the output file and the expected one?

Comment: Where is the file being output to - a Windows, Mac or Linus machine?

Comment: Hi Both,

It was a Windows machine, it turned out by taking away \r\n and just having \n was enough.

Answer (score 0):

replacing "\r\n" with "\n" works in CLI.